MySql query graphing in Grafana
I would like the following query to plot in Grafana by day of the year each year in a data series which is the KWh output of our solar panels.
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(DateStamp, '%m-%d') AS MonthDay,
    MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(DateStamp) = 2020 THEN ROUND(SolarOutputInKWHs, 1) END) AS `2020`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(DateStamp) = 2021 THEN ROUND(SolarOutputInKWHs, 1) END) AS `2021`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(DateStamp) = 2022 THEN ROUND(SolarOutputInKWHs, 1) END) AS `2022`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(DateStamp) = 2023 THEN ROUND(SolarOutputInKWHs, 1) END) AS `2023`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(DateStamp) = 2024 THEN ROUND(SolarOutputInKWHs, 1) END) AS `2024`
FROM (
    SELECT DateStamp, SolarOutputInKWHs FROM teslapowerwall.DailyAggregatedKWHs
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateStamp, SolarOutputInKWHs FROM teslasolar.DailyAggregatedKWHs
) AS CombinedData
GROUP BY MonthDay
ORDER BY MonthDay;

This outputs:
A row of 01-01 and a KWh value for each year 2020 through 2024.

Unfortunately when I insert into Grafana and try and time series the query it fails to create a data series for each year of KWh values.

Anyone help please?
